# using the get function in php to get results from mysql

Tags: php, api, function

i am new to php and i am trying to write a function which will get all the results from the `reviews` mysql table. I have posted what i have tried but its saying i have a problem on line 101 which is the `"$sql = 'SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE id = "'.$review_id.'";'"` and i cant see what the problem is can someone help please. im using apigee to test the api

```
/*reviews*/
function reviews_get() {
    $this->load->database();
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM reviews;';
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $data = $query->result();

    $this->response($data, 200);
}

function review_get($review_id) {
    $this->load->database();
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE id = "'.$review_id.'";';
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $data = $query->row();

    $this->response($data, 200);
}
```

Comment: why dont you try to fire the query directly in MySQL and see if same problem persists? If no then the problem in on PHP side otherwise the problem is in query.

Comment: post the error message.

Comment: Ive just edited some of the code now and re run it in apigee console and 200 success code but its not displaying any results such as reviews that are in my reviews mysql table

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the ";" from the end of the query string and your problem will be solved

Comment: getting this error now Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE in /home/3839203/public_html/filmreview/v1.0/application/controllers/test.php on line 101

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL statement is wrong . It should be

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE id = ".$review_id;
```

Comment: my sql table is called "reviews"